# Connecting to FTP via ftp:// with a username containing an @

Tags: php, ftp

I learned that you can use an url for things like filesize(),filetype(),isdir() and etc.

This url is:
    ftp://user:password@example.com/pub/fichier.txt

But, I am wondering what if your username is lets say sjobs@apple.com

Would i write the url like this:

```
ftp://sjobs@apple.com:funpassword@ftp.apple.com/pub/ficher.txt
```

Also, CPanel on shared hosting does not appear to give the option to connect without an @ symbol.

In other words, how do I login via ftp://user:password@example.com when the username is dog@cat.com.

Thanks
Cyrus

Comment: Encode the `@` in the username as `%40` and it should work I think. [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

> The user name (and password), if present, are followed by a
>      commercial at-sign "@". Within the user and password field, any ":",
>      "@", or "/" must be encoded.

Use [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) - see Example #1